# Continuous or command word false life item?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

Would it be possible to craft a continuous or a command word trigger false life item? Thus granting essentially a +10 hp? As it could be either constantly activated or activated repeatedly until +10 hp was achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A command-word *false life* item would indeed be possible, granting 1d10+3 temporary hit points for 3 hours each time (assuming minimum caster level). The magic item pricing guidelines would suggest a base cost of \$2 \times 3 \times 1\,800\text{ gp} = 10\,800\text{ gp}\$ for this item, which seems reasonable enough to me.

A continuous *false life* item would be useless, however: there would be no way to “refresh” the effect. Continuous doesn’t mean “constantly cast on you” but rather it just changes the duration, so you would get the *false life* effect (1d10+3 temporary hit points) with an endless duration, instead of 3 hours. But once lost, there would be no way to get those temporary hit points *back*; you cannot heal lost temporary hit points, they are simply gone once you have lost them. I guess you could remove the item and put it back on to restart the effect and get a new set of points, but that isn’t supremely convenient.

Comment: [A *Pathfinder* alternative](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/emerald-ellipsoid-ioun-stone/) in case you feel like adding it.

Comment: Would the same apply for something like command activated bears endurance?

Comment: @Khaldhool no, because, per [the spell description](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/bearsEndurance.htm), "Hit points gained by a temporary increase in Constitution score are not temporary hit points."  However, the custom item guidelines do suggest that items be priced according to similar effects; a continuous item of Bear's Endurance is basically the same thing as an Amulet of Health +4, and should be priced as such.